# Class resulting in NaN instead of a number

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor

I tried creating a class `BankAccount` in which another class `SavingsAccount` extends it. I then created an instance of the class `janesAccount`, called the deposit method and logged to the console its balance after any of the methods have been called (i.e deposit() or withdraw())

But instead of it to console.log 2000, it logs NaN instead.
[image]

Every idea I seem to have either results in an error or doesn't log anything to the console.

Comment: In your SavingsAccount's constructor, super() should have the same arguments as its parent's constructor; which right now is not the case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with class inheritance in JS, but your SavingsAccount constructor has 2 parameters, whereas you are passing 4, and the two classes' constructors' parameters are different.

Comment: Links to images expire eventually. When the link expires, this post will be of no use to others. Make your content useful to others by not posting pictures of code.

Comment: Your question should include the code in question, not a screenshot of your editor.

Comment: @Aralicia already let you know the problem.  Since you are passing one parameter in the sub/child class to the parent constructor, that sets accountNumber.  Parameters are positional.  You pass one parameter, and that sets accountNumber.  This is why balance is unset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aralicia and @mykaf pointed out, your *subclass* `SavingsAcccount` constructor is missing two parameters required by the *superclass* `BankAccount`: `accountNumber` and `accountHolderName`, an so is the `super()` call to the superclass constructor.

When you pass only the `balance`, this argument is taken as the `accountNumber`, but the constructor of `BankAccount` expects 3 arguments and `undefined` is passed instead, causing your bug.

Here's a fixed and improved version of your code:

```js
class BankAccount {
  constructor(accountNumber, accountHolderName, balance) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  deposit(amount) {
    this.balance += amount;
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    this.balance -= amount;
  }

  getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
  }
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
  constructor(accountNumber, accountHolderName, balance, interestRate) {
    super(accountNumber, accountHolderName, balance);
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
  }

  calculateInterest() {
    return this.getBalance() * (this.interestRate / 100);
  }
}

const janesAccount = new SavingsAccount(123456, "Jane Doe", 1000, 0.05);

janesAccount.deposit(1000);
console.log(janesAccount.getBalance());
```

I made your OOP program a little bit more dynamic by adding an `amount` parameter to `deposit()` and `withdraw()` methods to allow specifying different amounts for the operations.

Answer (score 3):

Your `super(balance)` call does not have enough arguments. Therefore, the only argument being taken into account is the `accountNumber`. So instead of the object being constructed with `this.balance = balance`, it is constructed with `this.balance = null` or `this.balance = NaN`. You are also passing too many parameters to the `SavingsAccount` constructor. Fix it so it takes the parameters.

SavingsAccount `constructor`:

```
class SavingsAccount{
var interestRate;
constructor(num, name, bal, rate)
{
    super(num, name, bal);
    this.interestRate = rate;

}
...//other code here
}
```